# Issue with paperjs add point after zooming

Tags: canvas, zooming, point, paperjs

I am using image annotation on canvas using paperjs. When i annotate on image without zooming it is working perfect.

```
                    path = new p.Path();
                    path.selected = false;
                    path.strokeColor = update.color;
                    path.strokeWidth = scope.lineWidth;
                    path.strokeCap = scope.strokeCap;
                    path.strokeJoin = scope.strokeJoin;
                    path.uuid = update.uuid;
                    var start = new p.Point(update.fromX, update.fromY);                        
                    path.moveTo(start);
                    p.view.draw();
```

But after zooming using `paper.view.zoom=2` then i am trying to draw a line on canvas but line alignment is not matching to my mouse point.

If i zoomout to initial point then it is aligning correctly.Please let me know how to fix this issue.

How to load with default coordinates? I mean now i have pan the canvas and reloaded. I have to display canvas with old co-ordinates.is it possible?

```
toolPan = new p.Tool();
                        toolPan.onMouseDrag = function (event) {
                            if(panCanvasStatus==1){
                                var a = event.downPoint.subtract(event.point);
                                a = a.add(p.view.center);
                                p.view.center = a;                                 
                                 update.pan=JSON.stringify(event);
                                sendUpdate('otWhiteboard_panupdate', update);
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to find the problem with the code snippet you provided but here is an example demonstrating a possible implementation of what you are describing.
Click on the canvas to add a point to the path and click on buttons to zoom in or out.

```js
// setup paper
paper.install(window);
paper.setup(document.getElementById('canvas'));

// draw image
var raster = new Raster({
  source: 'https://picjumbo.com/wp-content/uploads/vineyards-on-italian-coast-free-photo-DSC04256-1080x720.jpg',
  onLoad: function() {
    this.fitBounds(view.bounds.scale(0.8));
  }
});

// init path
var path = new Path({
  segments: [view.center],
  strokeColor: 'red',
  strokeWidth: 5
});

// on mouse down...
view.onMouseDown = function(event) {
  // ...add down point to the path
  var point = event.point;
  path.add(point);
};

// on button click...
$('#zoom-in').click(function() {
  // ...zoom in
  view.zoom *= 1.1;
});
$('#zoom-out').click(function() {
  // ...zoom out
  view.zoom *= 0.9;
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#zoom-in {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

#zoom-out {
  position: fixed;
  top: 35px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.11.5/paper-core.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<button id="zoom-in">zoom in</button>
<button id="zoom-out">zoom out</button>
```

### Edit

Now you provided your code, I can see that the event point coordinates you are using is not coming from `Paper.js` event but from an external event handling system. Thus you need to convert point coordinates into `Paper.js` coordinates system (including zoom, translations, ...).
You can do that using the method [view.viewToProject(point)](http://paperjs.org/reference/view/#viewtoproject-point).
I made a [Pull Request](https://github.com/muralibobby35/tokboxAnnotation/pull/1/files?utf8=%E2%9C%93&diff=split&w=1) to your repository including the needed changes. It add an helper method and use it to convert a point between both coordinates systems.

```
function createPoint(x, y) {
    return paper.view.viewToProject(new paper.Point(x,y));
};
```

Comment: Here you can download my code and run test.html once. I have updated it as you sugguested. but mouse point not equall to addpoint after zoomin zoomout.
https://github.com/muralibobby35/tokboxAnnotation

Comment: sorry please check demo.html

Comment: @murali-krishna, I updated my answer to solve your specific problem.

Comment: thank you so much @saseni. it is working fine. thanks a lot.

Comment: @Sasensi- How to always load image as below to points ? I have added this after raster image loaded. raster.insertBelow(path); But it only coming below to last draw point

Comment: I have added layer.sendToBack();. wroking fine.

Comment: How to load with default coordinates? I mean now i have pan the canvas and reloaded. I have to display canvas with old co-ordinates.is it possible?

Comment: could you please open my code in two browsers. click on pan button and drag image on one browser. how can i reflect the same in another browser?

Comment: Could you please post this problem as another question since it is not related to the original one, otherwise, question and answer won't be useful/readable for other users.

Comment: added a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53223643/issue-with-paperjs-rotate

Comment: @saseni I have added my new updated js file. Please open application in two browsers. click on image then it reflects into another browser. If you rotate it on one browser it is rotating in other browser. But when you refresh one browser there you can see rotaion view (rotation is ok but zoom issue)