# issue with paperjs rotate

Tags: rotation, zooming, paperjs

Using paperjs if I rotate `p.view.rotate(update.deg);` it is working fine with out issue.

If I refresh the page and call the above function `p.view.rotate(update.deg);` onload then the view is different. it is displaying a slight zoom.

default image rotation

[image]

After reloading the page I am rotating `p.view` with the previous value. then it is displaying as

[image]

Here is my js file

https://github.com/muralibobby35/annotateJs/blob/master/opentok-whiteboardnew.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to run your code but I would suggest, for an easier project state preservation, that you use transformations (scale, rotation, ...) through layer rather than through view.
That would allow you to easily export/import your project whithout having to manually restore state by calling `view.rotate()` like methods on window reload.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xidi2xidi/a3j1kr8d/1/) demonstrating the solution.
It simulates window reload by exporting/importing a project from one canvas to another empty one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Debug Paper.js</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.11.5/paper-full.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin   : 0;
            overflow : hidden;
            height   : 100%;
        }

        main {
            display : flex;
            height  : 100vh;
        }

        canvas {
            flex   : 1;
            border : 1px solid;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <canvas id="canvas1" resize></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas2" resize></canvas>
</main>
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas1">
    // draw a square
    var rectangle = new Path.Rectangle({
        from: view.center - 50,
        to: view.center + 50,
        fillColor: 'orange'
    });

    // rotate layer rather than view so transformations are persisted when exporting
    project.activeLayer.rotate(30);

    // export datas and store them in global variable just for the demo, to simulate a page reload
    window.exportedDatas = project.exportJSON();
</script>
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas2">
    // import the exported datas
    project.importJSON(window.exportedDatas);

    // see that rotation is preserved
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok but i am getting paper.activeLayer is undefined when i use like paper.activeLayer.rotate(30)

Comment: If i use project then i am getting project is not defined

Comment: This is because you are using `Paper.js` in `JavaScript` context and my example code is in `PaperScript` context (see this [article](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly/) for an explanation of the differeneces between both contexts). What you need to do basically is prefix `project` with `paper.` => `paper.project.activeLayer`.

Comment: Hi sasensi..hope you are doing good. could you please help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55509206/paperjs-pointtext-onhover-select-and-resize