# paperjs pointtext onhover select and resize

Tags: text, resize, drag, point, paperjs

I am trying to add pointtext on canvas using paperjs. i am able to create pointtext on canvas but need to handle drag and resize of text.

```
scope.drawText = function () {
               var pointTextLocation = new p.Point(100,100);
                var myText = new p.PointText(pointTextLocation);
                myText.fillColor = 'red';
                myText.fontSize= 25;
                myText.content = 'Sample Text';
            };
```

is it possible to do like below screen using paperjs.

I didn't find anywhere on google. Please suggest how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is possible (using `Item.scaling`) but you will have to code the scaling box yourself (by drawing it with regular shapes interacting with mouse and keyboard events). This hand made scaling box will control your `PointText.scaling` and `PointText.rotation` properties.

The scaling box is not simple to code, neither hard, and I am very sorry to notice that, as often, this is an extremely frequent problem which does not have a standard solution yet (too many solutions to implement such scaling box), and to my knowledge there are no good code snippet to rely on yet.

Comment: Related questions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876892/resize-the-width-and-height-of-shape-not-scaling-in-paperjs

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785966/transform-bounding-box-in-paper-js/26788306#26788306

Comment: [Sketch selection](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.8/S/ZY+7DsIwDEV/JcrSIlWoILEUdWJlQCobZQipERGpXaXmLf6dmC5FDB7u9bl+vDSaFnShqzOwPelMW2pEX01QHTnkLdx5TdawI1SlQripjfjpLM+zWJNlHWoUvH0IO2ZEp39ThsRAT4/O+xV5CjGXBGiSnyYhV+4JpZovxr6NPqCsSirTdh6U2EN0hPXgwTI0keNwgfjcIYA5fw/qdbHbvz8=) would be one of simple example for scaling box.

Answer (score -1):

i have updated my code.I am able to create pointtext and dragging anywhere else in canvas. [check here](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.8/S/lZNPi8IwEMW/ypBLWxCpC16UnvTowkK9rXuI6XQNTZOSpO4f8btvElxx17RgoIdM3vzey7Q9EUlbJAtSNmjZgUwIU5Xfw5Fq6BSXdoufdqMYtVxJKEDiB7z4ejrL84l7suVO7yT8WfcVCMD2y9NuKX6f3vnEmHDpntZciJUSSjtOorFKRsVK2pJ/YwFP8zEdczqUPlpS0rYTCL4cR49glFyrfi9wJThrHKzuJfMXSvHo6BmcYr1+2QM3N2HnedT5PGr9sCmv0+BrUCCzWGWDymvEX6lzocJgNGVIiu50GPePZXWPS4hPdvDeMNAQF1+n9Kx6g2tN3x+Z1KW7U4Z7fRH00/Ddxl+U+5P2GmkTJIYsXt/OPw==)

But when i double click i have to edit text. How to do it?

```
var pointTextLocation = new p.Point(x,y);

                var myText = new p.PointText(pointTextLocation);
                myText.fillColor = 'red';
                myText.fontSize= 25;
                myText.content = 'Sample Text';

                myText.onDoubleClick = function(event) {
                    this.fontSize= 50;
                }
                myText.onClick = function(event) {
                    if(this.selected){
                        this.selected= false;
                    }else{
                     this.selected= true;   
                    }

                }
                 myText.onMouseDrag = function(event) {
                    myText.position=event.point;
                }
```

Comment: any body plz help on this